# When a function accepts a forwarding reference to another function, what is the impact of calling the function using std::forward

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Just wondering what is the exact impact (and advantage) of forwarding the function template parameter, i.e:

```
template <class F>
void foo(F &&f) {
   f(1);                    // how does this call
   std::forward<F>(f)(1);   // differ from this one?
}
```

Comment: it calls rvalue `operator()(...)&&` (if it exist) when `f` is `F&&`

Answer (score 5):

only if the function overloaded `operator()` by l/rvalue

```
struct X{
    void operator()(int)&;  // 1
    void operator()(int)&&; // 2
};

template <class F>
void foo(F &&f) {
   f(1);                    // always calls 1
   std::forward<F>(f)(1);   // calls 2 when F is rvalue
}
```

---

the general move semantic applies, after you invoke `f` as rvalue, you should not use it again. (unless you check the state)

Comment: Assume a rvalue is passed, will just the fact of casting it using std::forward<F>(f) cause the F move constructor to be called to create a temporary object? And if not, then the state should not change, right?

Comment: @greg_p no, nothing is copied, but the state is supposed to be changed in the `&&` overload which qualify `this`. (to be complete, also `&` without `const`, but move out is a little different from modify)

Comment: @greg_p for example, `f` may contains some one-time resource that used up after the function call.

Comment: @greg_p it's like invoke a function with `void foo(X&&)`, the `X` is not copied by the call (just capture by rvalue reference), but it's supposed to be move-out after the invocation.